# How can I squash these SQL Server results into one row per customer key

Tags: sql-server, merge, unique

I've managed to gather our customers latest marketing preferences into the following form but can't figure out how to get these results to compress into one row per `[CustomerKey]`. Here's an example, obviously we have hundreds of thousands of actual results when I run the query further below.

```
CustomerKey                 SMS   Phone   Email   Post   Group
--------------------------------------------------------------
ClarkeM21-9EF1976-08-03                                  No
ClarkeM21-9EF1976-08-03                           No
ClarkeM21-9EF1976-08-03                   No
ClarkeM21-9EF1976-08-03           No
ClarkeM21-9EF1976-08-03     No
SmithNG12-8AS1980-02-03                                  No
SmithNG12-8AS1980-02-03                           No
SmithNG12-8AS1980-02-03                   Yes
SmithNG12-8AS1980-02-03           No
SmithNG12-8AS1980-02-03     Yes
```

This is the rather repetitive query I used to create the above just in case anyone looks at it and thinks I'm coming at this from entirely the wrong angle;

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#ClientRefPreferenceDates') IS NOT NULL 
     DROP TABLE #ClientRefPreferenceDates;
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#MaxDatePerClientRef') IS NOT NULL 
     DROP TABLE #MaxDatePerClientRef;
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#LatestPrefsbyCustKey') IS NOT NULL 
     DROP TABLE #LatestPrefsbyCustKey;

SELECT  
    mcp.[CustomerKey],
    mcp.[SMS],
    MAX(mcp.[SMS_DateTime]) AS SMSDate,
    '' AS Phone,
    '' AS PhoneDate,
    '' AS Email,
    '' AS EmailDate,
    '' AS Post,
    '' AS PostDate,
    '' AS [Group],
    '' AS GroupDate
INTO 
    #ClientRefPreferenceDates
FROM 
    [audit].[Marketing_Consent_Prefs] mcp
WHERE 
    mcp.[EndDate] IS NULL
GROUP BY 
    CustomerKey, SMS

UNION ALL

SELECT  
    mcp.[CustomerKey],
    '' AS SMS,
    '' AS SMSDate,
    mcp.[Phone],
    Max(mcp.[Phone_DateTime]) AS PhoneDate,
    '' AS Email,
    '' AS EmailDate,
    '' AS Post,
    '' AS PostDate,
    '' AS [Group],
    '' AS GroupDate
FROM
    [audit].[Marketing_Consent_Prefs] mcp
WHERE 
    mcp.[EndDate] IS NULL
GROUP BY  
    CustomerKey, Phone

UNION ALL

SELECT  
    mcp.[CustomerKey],
    '' AS SMS,
    '' AS SMSDate,
    '' AS Phone,
    '' AS PhoneDate,
    mcp.Email,
    MAX(mcp.[Email_DateTime]) AS EmailDate,
    '' AS Post,
    '' AS PostDate,
    '' AS [Group],
    '' AS GroupDate
FROM 
    [audit].[Marketing_Consent_Prefs] mcp
WHERE 
    mcp.[EndDate] IS NULL
GROUP BY CustomerKey, Email

UNION ALL

SELECT  mcp.[CustomerKey],
    '' AS SMS,
    '' AS SMSDate,
    '' AS Phone,
    '' AS PhoneDate,
    '' AS Email,
    '' AS EmailDate,
    mcp.Post,
    Max(mcp.[Post_DateTime]) AS PostDate,
    '' AS [Group],
    '' AS GroupDate
FROM [audit].[Marketing_Consent_Prefs] mcp
WHERE mcp.[EndDate] IS NULL
GROUP BY CustomerKey, Post

UNION ALL

SELECT  mcp.[CustomerKey],
    '' AS SMS,
    '' AS SMSDate,
    '' AS Phone,
    '' AS PhoneDate,
    '' AS Email,
    '' AS EmailDate,
    '' AS Post,
    '' AS PostDate,
    mcp.[Group],
    Max(mcp.[Group_DateTime]) AS GroupDate
FROM [audit].[Marketing_Consent_Prefs] mcp
WHERE mcp.[EndDate] IS NULL
GROUP BY CustomerKey, [Group]

SELECT  CustomerKey,
    SMS,
    Phone,
    Email,
    Post,
    [Group]
FROM #ClientRefPreferenceDates 
GROUP BY CustomerKey, SMS, Phone, Email, Post, [Group]
ORDER BY CustomerKey
```

Comment: It might be helpful to also show us sample input data and the expected output (if the current output is not also what you want).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way will be to wrap your query in another `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT CustomerKey, MAX(SMS), MAX(Phone), MAX(Email), MAX(Post), MAX(Group)
FROM (
    your query
) a
GROUP BY CustomerKey
```

Answer (score 0):

Window function should do it

```
SELECT  distinct 
    mcp.[CustomerKey],
    mcp.[SMS],
    Max(mcp.[SMS_DateTime]) over   (partition by CustomerKey, SMS)  AS SMSDate,
    Max(mcp.[Phone_DateTime]) over (partition by CustomerKey, Email) AS PhoneDate
INTO #ClientRefPreferenceDates
FROM [audit].[Marketing_Consent_Prefs] mcp
WHERE mcp.[EndDate] IS NULL
GROUP BY
```